# Terraform - Issues Converting From Decimal To Percentage

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to convert decimal numbers to percentages using Terraform. It works for some decimals, but not others.

For example:

```
$ terraform console
> 0.2 * 100
20
> 0.01 * 100
0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999
> 0.005 * 100
0.49999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999996
```

Calling `ceil` or `floor` won't be appropriate in this case.

I've replicated this behaviour in Terraform 1.1.4 and 1.2.3.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Can I ask what is your use case?

Comment: This looks more like a Go typing issue than anything else, and it is not uncommon in languages where you implicitly type in the code (TF not allowing you to explicitly Go type here and such). You can get there partially with `format`, but nothing will completely achieve what you are looking for here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Could you elaborate on why it only solves the issue partially?

Comment: @Will I missed the part in the documentation where it supports `float`, so actually `format` does solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update using [format()](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format) as suggested by @Matt Schuchard :

```hcl
tonumber(format("%.2f",  0.2 * 100)) # 20
tonumber(format("%.2f",  0.01 * 100)) # 1
tonumber(format("%.2f",  0.005 * 100)) # 0.5
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't address the problem that the answers are incorrect - `0.01*100` should equal `1`, not `0.99`.

Comment: I've update my answer to something that seems to match your issue :)